# Why does my graph measured in an Michelson interferometer look like this?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

[image: length vs intensity of Michelson interferometer]

I did an Michelson interferometer experiment and this is the result. 
I think the reason why the intensity is getting smaller is because the translation motor was a bit off.
But I don't understand why there is a small peak between the larger peak (which is the correct peak cause its max intensity is twice the intensity of the laser).

Comment: What type of laser did you use as the light source?

Comment: What is the setup of the experiment and how are the axis of the graph labeled?

Comment: I used (OBIS) 405nm multi mode cw diode laser. The x-axis is movement of one of the mirror(mm) and the y-axis is the power where the two beams meet(mW).

Comment: I assume multimode means it has transverse multimodes (spatial profile of the beam is not single mode Gaussian). But have you also checked if the laser is operating longitudinally single mode (only single frequency peak)?

Comment: I think it would help if you could put a link to the spectrum of the laser you are using, if it is available.

Comment: @IamAStudent yeah, these look like interferograms from a broadband source. I bet that laser has a messy spectrum.

Comment: Try applying a Fourier transform to your interferogram to compute the spectrum of your laser (like in FTIR spectroscopy), then ask yourself if it looks reasonable and/or matches other data you may have.  Do you by chance have access to a little grating spectrometer to corroborate?

Comment: @Gilbert, now I am pretty convinced that the signals are from a multimode spectrum. If it's a broadband source like superluminescent diode, then the fringe should occur at only one location (exactly balanced arm). But if the spectrum has many modes separated by free spectral range of the cavity, with some Gaussian envelope, I think it can give rise to those periodic revivals of fringes, which looks very non-sinusoidal.

Comment: That makes sense for the large peaks (which are revivals) but are you suggesting its the same for the smaller ones too? I was wondering if unwanted reflections could made those smaller peaks. Like BS's or mirrors.